# Post content in wordpress appears twice

Tags: wordpress

All the contents of my posts are shown twice in the same post. Here is the example:

[Duplicated content in a post](http://joe-learning.com/?p=377)

It happens for all the posts but not in page. I tried any other themes, it's the same result.

Any idea what could be the reason? Thanks.

Comment: post the code so that i can understand where is the problem

Comment: @Exprator What code you want to see?

Comment: show me the code where you are printing the content. the single.php or any custom template where you have written the code for displaying the content

Comment: Found the problem already. It caused by a plugin: Adsense Made Easy. It will show the content twice if I setup the ads in the bottom of post. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the line `the_content()` is repeated twice in the file single.php of your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
the_content();
```

or

```
 echo get_the_content();
```

don't use this code:

```
echo the_content();
```

Comment: How is that possible? All the theme got the same problem. You mean all code are wrong?

By the way, there is no the_content() in my single.php.